# react/prop-types and flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

My `.eslintrc` looks like this and I am using flow:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/flowtype",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype",
    "react",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2016,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", {
      "singleQuote": true,
      "trailingComma": "none",
      "bracketSpacing": true,
      "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
      "parser": "flow"
    }]
  },
  "settings": {
    "flowtype": {
      "onlyFilesWithFlowAnnotation": true
    }
  }
}
```

I am still getting react `react/prop-types` even though I am using flow.

Is this correct and should I just turn them off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PropTypes are for runtime type checking, while Flow is for static type checking. Both serve their own purpose, not all type errors can be caught during compilation, so PropTypes helps you with those; Flow can catch some errors early - before you interact with your app, or even load it to the browser.

Comment: using both would be a maintenance nightmare

Comment: It's true, but I have used both in a fairly large project. In practise, we used PropTypes in some parts and Flow in others. One rule of thumb, was to use PropTypes with reusable (container) components, as we can catch easy errors in those, like providing `id` prop as string instead of number. Usually those happen when we handover Ajax results as-is to the component. Flow, on the other hand, has helped in checking typing in functions (e.g., helpers) and maintaining it consistent when composing and chaining functions.